# error:spawn a process with only argument which is a recursive function that calls io:format

Tags: erlang

I use EUNIT module and including "eunit/include/eunit.hrl". I call spawn/1 with the argument func/0 to spawn a new  process in a test function and call io:format/1 in the new process. The argument func/0 is a recursive function like this:

```
func() -> 
A = 2,
io:format("#######~p~n", [A]),
timer:sleep(1000),
func().
```

Then

```
10> bt:test().
All 2 tests passed.
ok
11>
=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Jun-2013::19:50:54 ===
Error in process <0.122.0> with exit value: {terminated,[{io,format,[<0.121.0>,"
#######~p~n",[2]],[]},{bt,func,0,[{file,"bt.erl"},{line,6}]}]}
```

What's wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way fun() is written, it's infinite recursive. It's basically:

```
fun() ->
  fun().
```

That will never return (keep running) and is probably the reason for termination by EUNIT.

Answer (score 2):

If I correcly understand the problem is that you are spawning a process running a never ending function func(), but when the EUnit process terminates it probably **closes standard output**.

This makes the process issuing io:format() to exit (raises an exception). Indeed the ERROR REPORT mentions exactly this function.

My suggestion is to review the need of spawning a function that never ends.

Comment: Look at [this very detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6499774/1695036). It confirms my feelings about your issue (giving reasons, though).